# How to configure linux-virtual header files for VMWare?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware

I am trying to configure VMWare tools to work with the `linux-virtual` kernel, but every time I supply the headers path to `vmware-config-tools`, it rejects it. What should I do to configure it?

I am using the path:

```
/lib/modules/2.6.35-23-virtual/build/include
```

But I get the rejection message:

```
The path "/lib/modules/2.6.35-23-virtual/build/include" is not valid.
```

It works with the generic version, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you definitely have the headers installed? They are not installed automatically with the binary kernel builds. If not then it might be telling the truth and /lib/modules/2.6.35-23-virtual/build/include might not exist.

Assuming that you are running this kernel (double-check with `uname -a`) you can install the headers package with:

```
aptitude install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Comment: I definitely have the headers installed (via the `linux-headers-virtual` package), and the path certainly exists (tested using `ls`). However, executing `uname -r` yields "2.6.35-23-generic". Could this be the issue?

Comment: Yes it could, if the VMWare build script is verifying the header versions. You are currently running "2.6.35-23-generic" rather than "2.6.35-23-virtual". If you have rebooted since installing the alternative kernel build you migth need to do so again and select it explicitly from the Grub boot menu. If the grub menu does not appear automatically, hold the shift key at the appropriate time in the boot process.

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get install linux-source-2.6.35-23-virtual` should probably do it.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why I need the source in addition to the headers?

Answer (score 0):

While there is no reason to install the full source, since there is a persistent error it might be OK. Sometimes the folder exist but the script checks for some file there is not there. Rebooting it may help too.